# YTDL-CORE discordjs Error : Unable to retrieve video metadata

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, ytdl

When I use ytdl.getInfo,that throwing Error : Unable to retrieve video metadata
It was working at last week, but today it has stopped. I didn't change a code
But when I use VPN, it working good
How can I fix it?

Comment: you can see this issue \
[node-ytdl-core/issue/751](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/751) \
[node-ytdl-core/issue/813](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/813)  \

Comment: @myeongkilkim But when I use VPN, it working good

Comment: In the past, when I joined an app for Discord, I remember being rejected by YouTube's network's request limit. I don't remember how solved it, but it was an issue in the open source called [jmusicbot](https://github.com/jagrosh/MusicBot), and it seems necessary to check if it falls under this part.

Comment: You wanna say, that I have to wait YouTube let me send requests? Or watch how music made in jmusicbot? @myeongkilkim

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't elaborate on this part because it is a similar issue and only doubts, but it is not accurate.

Comment: in my case, i saw this and set it. [how-to-set-up-ipv6-ubuntu](https://monovm.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ipv6-on-ubuntu/) / [how-to-assign-ipv6-ubuntu-server](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-assign-ipv6-on-ubuntu-server/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer! I just deleted and install YTDL